# Pass credentials to Jmeter command line

Tags: command-line, parameters, scripting, jmeter

How can one pass credentials to the Jmeter command line to be used as username/password for HTTP Authorization Manager username/password? I'm using Jmeter 5.4.

I need to be able to programmatically pull credentials from a vault or Jenkins credentials and pass to Jmeter. Hard coding or writing to a file is not an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normal way of parameterizing a JMeter test using external data is:

1. Use [__P() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__P) in the HTTP Authorization Manager like:

   ```
   ${__P(username,)}
   ```

   [image]

   it will return the `username` property value
2. Pass the `username` property to JMeter via [`-J` command-line argument](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#override) like:

   ```
   jmeter -Jusername=johndoe -n -t test.jmx ....
   ```

Another option is reading the value from an environment variable using [__groovy() function](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black):

```
${__groovy(System.getenv('username'),)}
```

or if you have [Custom JMeter Functions](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/Functions/) plugin installed you can do the same using [__env() function](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/Functions/#envsupfont-color-gray-size-1-since-1-2-0-font-sup)

```
${__env(username,,)}
```